# Joomla 2.5 loadRenderer module error on Virtualmin server

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I'm new for this and encountering error when I migrating a joomla website. When I load the website the top menu giving below error. The rest of the websites are working fine.

[image: Instead showing menu its shows this error]

Hope someone can guide me on this.

The top menu throwing below error.

```
loadRenderer('module');
$params = array('style'=>$style);
$contents = '';
foreach (JModuleHelper::getModules($position) as $mod) {
    $contents .= $renderer->render($mod, $params);
} // this part allows html characters to show correctly
echo html_entity_decode($contents);
?>
```

Below is the code

```
            <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="blankdiv"></div>
        <nav class="topMenu">
          <?
                // extra code to make this work
                $style = -2; // set the style
                $position = "mainmenu"; // set the position of the modules to be loaded
                // end of extra code

                $document   = &JFactory::getDocument();
                $renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('module');
                $params      = array('style'=>$style);

                $contents = '';
                foreach (JModuleHelper::getModules($position) as $mod)  {
                $contents .= $renderer->render($mod, $params);
                }

                // this part allows html characters to show correctly
                echo html_entity_decode($contents);
            ?>
        </nav>
      </section>
```

Comment: Please provide all the possible details to help understand your problem better. Error message, for instance, is of key importance.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. already edit the question. Instead showing the top menu its showing the loadrenderer error. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That is not quite an error message, but rather a source code.

I would suggest to find which file contains these lines (they are likely multiple lines, so search by some fragment (e.g. `// this part allows html characters to show correctly`) and check if that file has a proper php opening tag, i.e. `<?php`.

Quite likely it will have either a shorthand (`<?`) or something else that may be incompatible/unsupported anymore. Make it to be `<?php`

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. You did save my day.

Comment: @KuganMV - marking the answer as accepted (if it was right and did actually help you) is the best form of 'thanks' around here :)